# Conditional execution of puppet defined resource type through exec

Tags: puppet

I have a requirement where one exec notifies another exec which notifies a defined resource type (which sets some variables and runs an internal exec). My understanding is that if the second exec fails, the defined resource type should NOT be refreshed. But it does... please let me know what is amiss here..

`

```
class test {
Exec  {
path => ['/usr/bin','/sbin','/bin'],
user => 'root',
}
  exec {
    "MAIN":
      command     => 'echo "MAIN EXEC FUNCTION OK"',
      onlyif      => 'test ! -f /var/log/no_file',
      logoutput   => true,
  }
  ~>
  exec {
    "SUB":
      command     => 'echo "SUB EXEC FUNCTION OK"',
      onlyif      => 'test -f /var/log/no_file',
      logoutput   => true,
      refreshonly => true,
  }
  ~>
  res_type {'TITLE':}
}
define  res_type () {
  exec {
    "$title":
      command     => 'echo "EXEC IN DEF RESOURCE TYPE"',
      refreshonly => true,
      logoutput   => true,
  }
}
include test
```

`

Here is the output of the puppet apply run `

```
puppet apply test.pp
Notice: Compiled catalog for test-server-0 in environment dev in 0.08 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Exec[MAIN]/returns: MAIN EXEC FUNCTION OK
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Exec[MAIN]/returns: executed successfully
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Exec[SUB]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Res_type[TITLE]/Exec[TITLE]/returns: EXEC IN DEF RESOURCE TYPE
Notice: /Stage[main]/Test/Res_type[TITLE]/Exec[TITLE]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.64 seconds
```

`

Answer (score 0):

> My understanding is that if the second exec fails, the defined resource type should NOT be refreshed. But it does... please let me know what is amiss here

But the second `Exec` *does not* fail.  It is never synced at all, because it is `refreshonly`, therefore it cannot fail.  Refreshing is a separate thing, though whether its command is executed upon refresh is governed by the same criteria.

Moreover, even if the second `Exec` were applied, it would be very surprising for it to fail.  Avoiding running the main `command` on account of the result of the `onlyif` command does not constitute a failure -- rather, that's a form of the `Exec` already being in sync.  A failure occurs only if the main command is run, and its exit code is not among those accepted as success (by default, only exit code `0` is accepted as successful).

I'd be inclined to say, however, that because the `Exec` is never applied, it should not notify the `Res_type`.  With its command not being run even upon refresh, it even more should not notify the `Res_type`. With that said, the behavior of `Exec`s with respect to events and refreshing has long been a troublesome matter, with a long list of tickets filed against various aspects.  See the list of issues related to [PUP-1106](https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1106), for example.

I don't think this particular behavior is the subject of a previous ticket, so you could consider filing one, but you probably should also find a better way to go about what you're trying to do.  Often `Exec`s are expedient, and sometimes they are even appropriate, but chaining them has a mild code smell, and relying on events generated by them has a stronger code smell.

Comment: John - Thank you for the reply. I will definitely search through previous tickets and open a new one if a relevant match is not found. Meanwhile, the above code (in much detailed form) is essentially logic that will detect whether a file  (presence of which determined by whether a generate heap action was successful) exists and tweak the subject line and body text for a custom resource type(that receives sub and body and sends email notifications).

Comment: @dasarp, since a custom resource type is already involved, perhaps it would be appropriate to revisit the design of that type.  It's hard to be sure, but it seems like at least some of the behavior of your `Exec`s would be more appropriately rolled into the custom type.